# Multi producer multi consumer wait free ring buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, shared-memory

I came across this statement while I was reading a paper on a queue implementation in C++ :

> For a design to be wait-free, a thread must be able to complete its operation in a finite amount of time. If a given thread cannot complete its operation, there is not system-wide progress. Without the progress assurance scheme, our algorithm may encounter a rare condition in which threads starve. With larger ring buffer sizes this possibility can be further reduced. This is because the larger capacity increases the number of operations between a given enqueue or a given dequeue making it less likely for threads to compete for the same buffer index

How come more number of operations between enqueue or dequeue will make less likely for threads to compete for same buffer index?

Link to the  paper: https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1531271

PS. Not sure if this is the right place to ask.

Comment: No link to the original paper for context. However, they may be describing something similar to thundering herd. For producers, if the queue is full, they end up herding around trying to put something in. For consumers, if the queue is empty, they end up herding around waiting for an item to come. Their suggestion only makes sense if you spend some time seeding the larger queue up with items before letting consumers start processing (like you would with buffering to reduce video playback jitter).

Comment: Agreed with @jxh about lack of context, _"our algorithm may encounter a rare condition"_ screams that it is context sensitive.

Comment: @jxh added link to the paper

Comment: @Bug Thanks. I don't think my opinion is changed. I will note that the stated limitation is in Section 5, but in their conclusions, they claim their solution has not live lock or starvation issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.